# Defining a unit with \DeclareSIUnit causes siunitx to throw an error

Tags: siunitx

I am trting to define a custom unit as follows

```
\DeclareSIUnit{\cmHg}{\centi\meter.\mathrm{Hg}}
```

In previous versions of `siunitx`, it was working very well. With the newest version it does not. Even the dot does not appear.

My MWE

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}, t, handout]{beamer}

\usetheme{Dresden}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\cmHg}{\centi\meter.\mathrm{Hg}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    
    $\si{\cmHg}$
    
    $\si{\centi\meter.\mathrm{Hg}}$
    
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Intermixing 'literal' and macro-based units has always been somewhat risky. In v3, a more controlled code path means that you do need to separate them out cleanly. As `cmHg` is a unit in it's own right, I would simply use

```latex
\DeclareSIUnit{\cmHg}{cmHg}
```

One could also treat this as an out-and-out qualifer

```latex
\DeclareSIUnit[qualifier-mode = space]{\cmHg}{\centi\metre\of{Hg}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, books usually provide the unit as `cm.Hg` (with a dot at the baseline). The dot still causes an error and even does not show up when typing `\si{\centi\meter.\mathrm{Hg}}`

Comment: A dot in a literal unit has always meant a space: that goes back to the syntax inherited from `SIstyle` over a decade ago!